# Optimizing following Python List of Dictionary operation with better solution

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a list of dictionary as :

```
records = [ 
            {"page":"A", "date":"2020-01-01", "value": 10, "metric":"engagement"},
            {"page":"A", "date":"2020-01-01", "value": 5, "metric":"clicks"},
            {"page":"B", "date":"2020-01-01", "value": 100, "metric":"engagement"},
            {"page":"B", "date":"2020-01-01", "value": 45, "metric":"clicks"},
            {"page":"A", "date":"2020-01-02", "value": 20, "metric":"engagement"},
            {"page":"A", "date":"2020-01-02", "value": 7, "metric":"clicks"},
          ]
```

And I want output like :

```
[
  { 
     "name": "A",
     "analytics": [
        {"date": "2020-01-01", "engagement":10, "clicks":5},
        {"date": "2020-01-02", "engagement":20, "clicks":7}
      ]
 },
 {
   "name": "B",
   "analytics": [
        {"date": "2020-01-01", "engagement":100, "clicks":45}
      ]
} ]
```

My current approach is given below.

```
    output = []
    page_result = OrderedDict({})
    date_result = OrderedDict({})
    for q in records:
        metric = q["metric"]
        date = q["date"]
        page = q["page"]
        if page not in page_result:
            page_result[page] = []

        if date not in date_result:
            date_result[date] = {}

        date_result[date][metric] = q["value"]
        date_result[date]["page"] = page

    for k,v in date_result.items():
        tmp = {"date":k}
        for k1,v1 in v.items():
            tmp[k1] = v1

        tmp.pop("page")
        page_result[v["page"]].append(tmp)


    for k, v in page_result.items():
        output.append({
                "name": k,
                "analytic": v
            })
```

I know my solution is not good this is not a pythonic way of doing. I assume this can be compressed with comprehension or pandas.
Can anybody suggest a better way of doing this ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged `pandas`, here is one way to do it in `pandas` using `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records)

result = [{"name":name, "analytics":(data.pivot(index="date",columns="metric",values="value")
                                    .reset_index().to_dict(orient="records"))}
          for name, data in df.groupby("page")]

print (result)

#
[{'name': 'A', 'analytics': [{'date': '2020-01-01', 'clicks': 5, 'engagement': 10},
                             {'date': '2020-01-02', 'clicks': 7, 'engagement': 20}]},
 {'name': 'B', 'analytics': [{'date': '2020-01-01', 'clicks': 45, 'engagement': 100}]}]
```